# Can I classify laugh words with char level tokenization?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I want to use Keras' tokenizer's `char_level` capability to train a model to classify if a word is a laugh or just a regular word, like "hello" (regular) and "hahaha", "looooool" (laugh). I am not sure this is the best way but I just want to try what would happen.

For English it may be easy. But in Turkish there is one thing called "random laugh", which you just smash the keyboard randomly like "asdpfjaefpkaods" to express that you lmao'ed.

I want to train a model that maybe it can learn "dpfj can't be in a sequence in a regular word, there should be an [a, e, i...]" (maybe I can add vowel and consonant features as well?)

So I just generated 40 words and trained a model. When I'm doing prediction, I wanted a probability of a single value for each word, but it generates for each character (in length of SEQ_LENGTH). Here what have I done so far basically:

```py
SEQ_LENGTH = 20
NUM_WORDS = 50

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=NUM_WORDS, char_level=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data.word)

X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data.word)
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=SEQ_LENGTH)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=NUM_WORDS, output_dim=20, input_length=SEQ_LENGTH))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', 'accuracy')
```

The training goes as:

```
Epoch 1/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 682us/step - loss: 0.6910 - accuracy: 0.5525
Epoch 2/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 797us/step - loss: 0.6880 - accuracy: 0.6650
Epoch 3/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 763us/step - loss: 0.6855 - accuracy: 0.7050
```

The prediction is for a single `["hahaha"]`:

```
array([[[0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.3136345 ],
        [0.90032935],
        [0.8137126 ],
        [0.90032935],
        [0.8137126 ],
        [0.9003294 ],
        [0.8137126 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

Did I misunderstand the purpose of char level tokenization? Thanks.

Comment: I just seen that I have forgotten to add a Flatten layer... Sorry for long post. I still need advices on the concept though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I notice your Embedding `output_dim=20` and the output you gave us is also length 20. I think maybe the output you are viewing is solely after the Embedding layer. You can see that the h's all have the same value `0.8137126` and the a's all have the same value `0.9003294` and then everything after is the pad value `0.3136345`. So I believe your model is only using 1 layer.